# USB mouse gets stuck on top right corner

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mouse, xorg

My USB mouse every now and then (which means pretty often :) gets stuck in the top right corner of the screen with no apparent reason. If I unplug and plug back the USB cable, then it resumes working fine. I'm running a standard Ubuntu 12.04. I'm pretty sure this happened with other mouses as well, while it didn't happen when this machine was running Vista, so I guess it's Ubuntu-Linux related.

Comment: A guessing game in solving a problem really is not something you wanna do. Can you please try mousing with a different mouse for a while to confirm it will also happen with that mouse? I once had a mouce that died on me and displayed similar behavor. Except it would suddenly stop doing horizontal movement, while vertical would still work, and after unplugging it and replugging it, it would work normal for a while.

Comment: @LPChip OK, will try and post back then